# Django OID token validation solutions

Tags: django-rest-framework, openid-connect

I am working on a Django `rest-framework` API. The frontend app (react) authenticates with a OpenID provider, and passes the authentication token to the API. I need to verify the authenticity of the token before serving the client requests.

As far as I understand, `OID` libraries that I have seen give a client and a provider implementation, but the above scenario seems to not be covered, i.e the API is neither a client, or a provider.

I have found one [source](https://connect2id.com/blog/how-to-validate-an-openid-connect-id-token) describing the validation steps required, but I was wondering if there is an opensource solution that I have not found yet that will perform validation of the token for me.

*Update*

This is the implementation I have made:

```
import requests
import datetime
import six
from logging import getLogger
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from calendar import timegm
from jwkest import JWKESTException
from jwkest.jwk import KEYS
from jwkest.jws import JWS
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication, get_authorization_header
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from .utils import class_cache


logger = getLogger(__name__)


def setting(key):
    return getattr(settings, f'OIDC_AUTH_{key}')


class AuthenticatedServiceClient:
    def __init__(self, roles, user_id):
        self.roles = roles
        self.id = user_id

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def create(payload, request):
        roles = payload.get('role', [])

        user_id = payload.get('sub', None)  # framework specific code
        if not user_id:
            msg = _('No sub claims provided')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        return AuthenticatedServiceClient(roles, user_id)


class NoAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        no_user_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        return AuthenticatedServiceClient.create({'sub': no_user_id}, request), True


class BaseOidcAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):

    @cached_property
    def oidc_config(self):
        url = urljoin(setting('OIDC_ENDPOINT'), '.well-known/openid-configuration')
        return requests.get(url, verify=setting("SSL_VERIFY")).json()


class BearerTokenAuthentication(BaseOidcAuthentication):
    www_authenticate_realm = 'api'

    def authenticate(self, request):
        bearer_token = self.get_bearer_token(request)
        if bearer_token is None:
            return None

        try:
            token_info = self.introspect_token(bearer_token)
        except HTTPError:
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. Unable to verify bearer token')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        logger.debug(f"Received token: {token_info}")
        self.validate_bearer_token(token_info)

        return AuthenticatedServiceClient.create(token_info, request), True

    def validate_bearer_token(self, token_info):
        if token_info['active'] is False:
            msg = _('Authentication Failed. Received Inactive Token')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        if setting('OIDC_SCOPE') not in token_info['scope']:
            msg = _('Authentication Failed. Invalid token scope')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        utc_timestamp = timegm(datetime.datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())
        if utc_timestamp > int(token_info.get('exp', 0)):
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. Bearer token has expired.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)

    def get_bearer_token(self, request):
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()
        auth_header_prefix = setting('BEARER_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX').lower()

        if not auth or smart_text(auth[0].lower()) != auth_header_prefix:
            msg = _('Authorization failed. No bearer token found in header')
            logger.error(msg)
            return None
        if len(auth) == 1:
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. No credentials provided')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        elif len(auth) > 2:
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. Credentials string should not contain spaces.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        elif smart_text(auth[1]).count('.') == 2:
            msg = _('Authorization failed. Unexpected token format')
            logger.error(msg)
            return None
        return auth[1]

    @class_cache(ttl=setting('BEARER_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME'))
    def introspect_token(self, token):
        response = requests.post(
            self.oidc_config['introspection_endpoint'],
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(setting('OIDC_SCOPE'), setting('OIDC_INTROSPECT_PASSWORD')),
            data={'token': token.decode('ascii')},
            verify=setting("SSL_VERIFY"))
        return response.json()


class JSONWebTokenAuthentication(BaseOidcAuthentication):
    """Token based authentication using the JSON Web Token standard"""

    www_authenticate_realm = 'api'

    def authenticate(self, request):
        jwt_value = self.get_jwt_value(request)
        if jwt_value is None:
            return None
        payload = self.decode_jwt(jwt_value)
        logger.debug(f"Received token: {payload}")
        self.validate_claims(payload)

        return AuthenticatedServiceClient.create(payload, request), True

    def get_jwt_value(self, request):
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()
        auth_header_prefix = setting('BEARER_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX').lower()

        if not auth or smart_text(auth[0].lower()) != auth_header_prefix:
            return None

        if len(auth) == 1:
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. No credentials provided')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        elif len(auth) > 2:
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. Credentials string should not contain spaces.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        elif smart_text(auth[1]).count('.') != 2:
            return None

        return auth[1]

    def jwks(self):
        keys = KEYS()
        keys.load_from_url(self.oidc_config['jwks_uri'], verify=setting("SSL_VERIFY"))
        return keys

    @cached_property
    def issuer(self):
        return self.oidc_config['issuer']

    @class_cache(ttl=setting('JWKS_EXPIRATION_TIME'))
    def decode_jwt(self, jwt_value):
        keys = self.jwks()
        try:
            id_token = JWS().verify_compact(jwt_value, keys=keys)
        except JWKESTException:
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. JWT Signature verification failed.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            msg = _('Bad token format. Token decoding failed.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        return id_token

    def get_audiences(self, id_token):
        return setting('AUDIENCES')

    def validate_claims(self, id_token):
        if isinstance(id_token.get('aud'), six.string_types):
            # Support for multiple audiences
            id_token['aud'] = [id_token['aud']]

        if id_token.get('iss') != self.issuer:
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. Invalid JWT issuer.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        if not any(aud in self.get_audiences(id_token) for aud in id_token.get('aud', [])):
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. Invalid JWT audience.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        utc_timestamp = timegm(datetime.datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())
        if utc_timestamp > id_token.get('exp', 0):
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. JWT has expired.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        if setting("ENABLE_NBF_CHECK") and 'nbf' in id_token and utc_timestamp < id_token['nbf']:
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. JWT not yet valid.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        if 'iat' in id_token and utc_timestamp > id_token['iat'] + setting('LEEWAY'):
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header. JWT too old.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        if setting('OIDC_SCOPE') not in id_token.get('scope'):
            msg = _('Invalid Authorization header.  Invalid JWT scope.')
            logger.error(msg)
            raise AuthenticationFailed(msg)

    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        return 'JWT realm="{0}"'.format(self.www_authenticate_real
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time it doesn't seem like there is an official library supporting it.
I have put together the following implementation, using https://github.com/ByteInternet/drf-oidc-auth as a base:

https://gist.github.com/latusaki/0f015643d55c2481bb7acd023c4203e3

Comment: the url: https://gist.github.com/latusaki/0f015643d55c2481bb7acd023c4203e3
 has been removed. Can you paste your solution here? I stuck in similar issue and need help

Comment: Will check what I can dig out